# select last tab from a text link in jQuery UI tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-tabs

I'm using jQuery UI tabs for product pages on my website. On some pages I have 2 tabs and on some 3. I would like to open last tab from a text link. The jquery tabs api just shows you how to go a particular tab if you know the tab index(let's say 2 to open 3rd tab). I tried the code below but it didn't help. Please advise. Thanks.

```
    $("#productTabs").tabs();
    var $tabs = $('#productTabs').tabs(); // first tab selected

    $("a[href$='mylink']").click(function(event){
    $tabs.tabs('select', -1); // switch to last tab
    return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically get the length of the tab group and subtract one to get the last index value.

```
$("a[href$='mylink']").click(function(event){
  $tabs.tabs('select', $tabs.tabs.("length") - 1); // switch to last tab
  return false;
});
```

Comment: thank you for putting me on the right track. I got it to work with slight modification by using $tabs.tabs("length") instead of $tabs.tabs.length()